# Graylog for dummies tutorial?

Tags: input, interface, stream, nodes, graylog

So I'm a complete computer science newbie, and I'm working with Graylog. Can someone provide an-easy-to-understand Graylog introduction and what the components on its user interface mean (like inputs, streams, nodes)? Please assume I know nothing, because all the sites and videos I've researched use technical terms that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this language but I know that you can search up the definitions of the word you do not understand.